# Google search for my site is missing "www" prefix

Tags: .htaccess, web, google-search

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775855/why-doesnt-google-show-www-for-my-website-on-searches), but changing the .htaccess file hasn't solved my problem.

I have addressed this issue by including the following two rules into my .htaccess file. It now correctly redirects any http requests without the www prefix, to the page with it. The problem now is that google is still displaying the site without the prefix. The homepage is showing on google with the www. prefix, but not other pages.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websitename.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.websitename.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Search Console:

> Specify a preferred domain: On the Search Console Home page, click the
>   site you want. Click the gear icon , and then click Site Settings. In
>   the Preferred domain section, select the option you want.

[Set your preferred domain (www or non-www)](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en)